# How to prevent the creation of Mysql columns with default values that are not defined

Tags: mysql

Is there a Mysql server setting that will prevent the creation of columns that are `NOT NULL` but do not have a default value specified?

I'm trying to prevent the creation of fields like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mydate DATE NOT NULL;
```

I know I can prevent INSERTs by setting `sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES`, but I want to prevent the creation of the columns in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such an option.  You could request such at bugs.mysql.com.

I disagree with making NULL (or, for that matter) NOT NULL mandatory.  NULL and NOT NULL have important uses in schema design and execution.  `PRIMARY KEYs` *must* be `NOT NULL`, and that is implicitly provided.  Due to business logic, *some* columns should not be left out; some *should* be allowed to be optional.

`NULL` has a lot of different semantics, and arbitrarily forcing all columns to be `NULL` begs the issue of which semantics you want.  Examples:  Optional (product specifications); not yet provided (an `end_date`); unknown (due to partial data received).

Comment: I'm not forcing NULL or NOT NULL, I trying to force the default value to be defined.  In my DATE example, what value will be read if the default value is not defined?  Should it be NULL or something else?

I'm trying to avoid mysql error 1364: Field does not have a default value.

Comment: @lfjeff - OK.  I like that one.  And I would opt for `NOT NULL` as the default since I have to explicitly think about why I want to use `NULL`.

Comment: Exactly.  Try a query like this and you'll see what I'm talking about:

`SELECT DEFAULT(mydate) FROM mytable LIMIT 1`

Comment: @lfjeff - Hmmm...  That is not a function that I have ever found a use for.

Comment: I can find the columns that are not fully defined using this query (from https://www.codediesel.com/mysql/avoiding-implicit-default-column-values-in-mysql):

    `USE information_schema;
 
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
 FROM `columns`
 WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
  AND COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA= 'YOUR-DATABASE-NAME'`

However, I'm trying to prevent the creation of columns with no default values in the first place.